# method ruby return true or false

Tags: ruby, count, block, each, ruby-1.9.2

I want get from a method ruby **true** if every posts are followed for a people and false if **not**.

I have this method:

```
def number_of_posts_that_are_followed
  user_to_be_followed = User.find(params[:id]) #users whose posts, will be followed by another user
  user_to_be_followed.posts.each do |this_post| 
    if current_user.follows?(this_board) == true #method that returns true if the current_user is following this post of the user whose posts will be followed
     return true
    else
     return false
    end 
   end
  end
```

**The problem is that this method return true if the first post (in the first iteration) its followed by current_user. I want return true if every posts are followed or false if not are followed.**

I have tried put a count like this:

```
count = user_to_be_followed.posts.count
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def number_of_posts_that_are_followed
  user_to_be_followed = User.find(params[:id]) #users whose posts, will be followed by another user
  value = true #will stay true unless changed
  user_to_be_followed.posts.each do |this_post| 
    if current_user.follows?(this_board) != true
      value = false
    end 
  end
  value #returned
end
```

Comment: I have not tested, but you may also be able to use `break` on the line immediately after `value = false`, to prevent extra looping

Comment: For your carma, I accept your response. It does works fine :D. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

You should use [Enumerable#all?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) method to check that all elements of the list match condition defined in predicate (block that returns boolean value).

> **all? [{|obj| block } ]** → true or false
>
> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method
>   returns true if the block never returns false or nil. If the block is
>   not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of {|obj| obj} (that is all?
>   will return true only if none of the collection members are false or
>   nil.)

```
def number_of_posts_that_are_followed
  User.find(params[:id]).posts.all? {|post| current_user.follows? post }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A little refactoring of SimonMayer's  :

```
def number_of_posts_that_are_followed
  User.find(params[:id]).posts.each do |this_post| 
    return false unless current_user.follows?(this_post)
  end
  true
end
```

**EDIT:**
Even shorter, ruby-style :

```
def number_of_posts_that_are_followed
  User.find(params[:id]).posts.map do |this_post| 
    not current_user.follows?(this_post)
  end.any?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_of_posts_that_are_followed
  user_to_be_followed = User.find(params[:id]) #users whose posts, will be followed by another user
  user_to_be_followed.posts.each do |this_post| 
    if current_user.follows?(this_board) != true
      return false
    end 
  end
  return true
end
```